# Remove VS 2010 from the list of debugging engines offered by vsjitdebugger.exe

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

I have Visual Studio 2015 installed and when an exception occurs vsjitdebugger.exe runs and pops up a dialog offering to choose between Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Studio 2015 as debugging engines. VS2010 isn't actually installed. How do I remove it from the list of debugging engines in that dialog?

Comment: This would require hacking the registry, the kind of advice an SO user would never post.  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Debugger\JIT key.  A failed or improper uninstall can cause many other possible problems, only decent way to do it is uninstall VS2015, rerun the VS2010 installer with the /uninstall /force options and reinstall VS2015.

Comment: No way am I going to uninstall VS2015 just to try to fix this. I'm happy to edit the registry, but what do I change under that key? There are 3 sub-keys, all GUIDs. None of them mention VS.

Comment: Subkeys of those subkeys.  {02CD4067-3D8F-4F9E-957F-F273804560C5} is VS2013, {CACE29C3-10A7-4B66-A8CA-82C1ECEC1FA3} is VS2015, no idea what VS2010 might be since I don't have it installed.  Do backup before you start hacking this.

Comment: Great, thanks! It seems that `{6F5BF5E0-D729-46dd-891C-167FE3851574}` is VS2010. Removing those keys did the trick. If you want to post this as an answer I'll accept it.